# THREE.WebGLProgram Shader Error because of defined v1 constant

Tags: three.js

I am using [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and I am loading an HDR as an environment map for the scene. Upon loading, I receive this error:

[image]

The line in questions is this:

[image]

I am assuming that the defined `v1` causes an issue in this line because it is not undefined.

[image]

I am loading the HDR map like this:

```js
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new RGBELoader()
          .setDataType(THREE.HalfFloatType)
          .load(
            path, // <-- hdr file
            (texture) => {
              // I tried fromEquirectangular and fromCubemap
              // const envMap = this.pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;
              const envMap = this.pmremGenerator.fromCubemap(texture).texture;
              texture.needsUpdate = true;
    
              resolve({ envMap });
            },
            undefined,
            reject
          );
        });
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue in THREE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const envMap = this.pmremGenerator.fromCubemap(texture).texture;

I doubt this method call is correct. `RGBELoader` can not load textures in the cube map format. You probably want to use `fromEquirectangular()`. Before using this method, you need this line in your `onLoad()` callback:

```js
texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
```

Besides, please check if the usage of `PMREMGenerator` is actually necessary in your app. In latest releases, `three.js` internally uses `PMREMGenerator` to prepare environment maps for the usage with PBR materials.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also tried `fromEquirectangular` with the same error but haven't tried the `THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping` constant yet. I will try that

Comment: That indeed worked! And I could remove `pmremGenerator` as well